# When is the Chest's Loot determined?

Tags: clash-royale

So I've recently got a Legendary Chest:
[image: Legendary Chest]

I really want to get that Inferno Dragon, so is it safe to unlock the Chest now and wait for that new Card? Or do I need to unlock it *after* it the Inferno Dragon appears?

Otherwise said: **Is the Loot inside the Chest determined when *unlocking* it or when *opening* it?**

Comment: By the way, I *did* get an Inferno Dragon from that Legendary Chest.

Answer (score 4):

Cards are determined on open.

Source: Orange Juice's channel. Pretty sure he gets info directly from SuperCell.